# suricata custom rule to store and alert all pdf files

Tags: suricata

I am trying to add a new rule to Suricata to store any PDF file transfer in network. I try to achieve that by two rules

> alert http any any -> any any (msg:"FILE pdf detected"; filemagic:"PDF
>   document"; filestore; sid:3; rev:1;)

and

> alert ftp any any -> any any (msg:"FILE pdf detected"; filemagic:"PDF
>   document"; filestore; sid:4; rev:1;)

the second rule always give me error as configuration error.

when I try first one only and try to download any pdf file fromm http page, no alert is reported

What I am missing here

Answer (score 0):

Is...

```
file-store:
    enable: yes
```

...set in your suricata.yaml?

You should also check what your particular version of filemagic returns for PDF files. Unfortunately the filemagic rules seem to need to exactly matches.

```
file file.pdf
```